# How do I loop though a text file, line by line, and append each line to an array?

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I'm trying to loop through a .txt, line by line, but there does not seem to be a good way to do this.

The idea is to extract each line and append it to an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider you have a text file like

[image]

and I'm trying to read the same file from blob storage. In order to make each line into an array, you can use a compose connector with a split() function in it. Here is my logic app screenshot for reference:-

[image]

Here is the split expression in compose connector

```
split(body('Get_blob_content_(V2)'),'
')
```

**RESULT**

[image]

Below is the Code view of my logic app:

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Compose": {
                "inputs": "@split(body('Get_blob_content_(V2)'),'\r\n')",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Get_blob_content_(V2)": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Compose"
            },
            "Get_blob_content_(V2)": {
                "inputs": {
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['azureblob']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "get",
                    "path": "/v2/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('AccountNameFromSettings'))}/files/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('JTJmY29udGFpbmVyMSUyZnNhbXBsZVRleHRGaWxlLnR4dA=='))}/content"
                },
                "metadata": {
                    "JTJmY29udGFpbmVyMSUyZnNhbXBsZVRleHRGaWxlLnR4dA==": "/container1/sampleTextFile.txt"
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {
            "$connections": {
                "defaultValue": {},
                "type": "Object"
            }
        },
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {},
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {
        "$connections": {
            "value": {
                "azureblob": {
                    "connectionId": "/subscriptions/<YourSubscriptionId>/resourceGroups/<YourResourceGroup>/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/azureblob",
                    "connectionName": "azureblob",
                    "id": "/subscriptions/<YourSubscriptionId>/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/northcentralus/managedApis/azureblob"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```